# What is the Default Pawn class and what is used for in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal

I'm newbie in Unreal Engine and also in games development.

I have developed my own version of Pong game (sources [here](https://github.com/ViaCognita/Unreal)) and I'm confuse with the behaviour of `DefaultPawnClass`: Its creating another Paddle in game (I posted a question about it [here](https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?145742-Another-player-appears-in-the-place-I-am-before-I-click-play-in-the-editor)).

I have to questions:

1. What is Default Pawn class?
2. And, what is it used for?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the 'Play' button in Unreal Editor, the engine spawns a pawn for you to control in the game. You can specify which *pawn* you want to spawn by DefaultPawnClass specified in the game mode.